# Displaying a survey on a web part page

Tags: 2010, web-part, survey-list

Is it possible to show a survey on a web part page?

I have a survey called *Do you like my site*. I see there is a webpart created for my survey automatically.

[Survey http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/ef701.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/ef701.png)

When I add it to the page I get the following:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/59771.png

Instead of this is possible to display the form to enter?

Comment: Cannot see any message or information under "I get the following: "

Comment: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/59771 link if it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing code, the only way I know of doing this is to create a minimal masterpage that shows only the main body, and then create a new "new item" form in SharePoint Designer and have it use the new minimal masterpage so that nothing but the new item form shows on the page, then put the link to this new page into a page viewer web part on the main page. Since Survey forms cannot be customized using InfoPath, you cannot use the InfoPath Form Web Part to show it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by simply following the below steps

1. In SharePoint designer, go to Insert> New Item Form >select your survey > select New item form (in radio button)
2. That's it there you go... you have new item form of your survey is added to your page without any hassle...
3. Click on Add Columns and Add the Columns to your questions.

And if you want to add this web part in any other part of the site.. then just save the web part in to gallery by 'Data view tools > To site gallery'. This data view tools ribbon can be activated by just clicking on tag